# xamarin android sqlite insert List objectes ti sqlite async

Tags: android, sqlite, xamarin

I try insert to sqlite List of objects i try do this :

```
public virtual async void InsertObjects(Context context, List<Object> objs)
    {
        lock (locker)
        {
            SQLiteDatabase db = new Helper(context).WritableDatabase;
            ContentValues Values = new ContentValues();
            foreach (Object obj in objs)
            {
                Values.Put(ColumnID, obj.id);
                Values.Put(ColumnUsername, obj.name);
                Values.Put(ColumnFullName, obj.symbol);
                await db.Insert(TableName, null, Values);
            }

            db.Close();
        }
    }
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: 1) What does not work??? 2) What Sqlite framework are you using?

Comment: @SushiHangover I use Android.Database.Sqlite and it work in ui thread